# Amazon EC2 Security Groups - IP ranges

Tags: amazon-ec2, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

So if I add `62.234.231.65/32` to my allowed IPs in security groups, does that mean that everyone with an IP from `62.234.231.0` to `62.234.231.255` can access the instance?

Comment: That's CIDR notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing and there are CIDR calculators, e.g., http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php

Comment: The `/32` means that all 32 bits need to match.

Answer (score 11):

If you mean the well-known IP/subnet notation, then this specifies a single IP address because of the subnet mask `/32`. If you want to have the range from 0 to 255 in the last octet, you need to specify `/24` as subnet mask.